Is it ok to have 2 taps of unequal sizes directly across from each other in a HVAC supply trunk?
I have a manufactured home and need to be a bit creative, due to physical barriers under the house, to fix the severely undersized ductwork for my house. I have a 4 ton package unit heat pump, so 1600 cfm of air, connected to an 18" "trunk" duct. If I put an 18"x 16"x 16" wye at the end of this and reduced one side to 12", would it push equal volumes out both sides with the smaller side going much faster or would I get about a 2 to 1 ratio of volume of air out of the 2 sides and speeds and pressures being fairly close to each other? The undersized ducts are further down the line but I have to get ducts to them first.

To clarify further, the 16" side would later be split into two 12" ducts. I'm trying to get three 12" ducts with equal pressures, volumes and speeds but space is giving me design issues.
